# _InterlockedCompareExchange vs _InterlockedCompareExchange_np

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86, windows-7-x64

I am developing a very specialized and very optimized kernel code (target Windows7 to Windows10, x64), and I need some of the Interlocked intrisics, in particular _InterlockedCompareExchange. The documentation says that there are many variants of the function, but for some of them the description is quite cryptic. MSDN says "The intrinsics with an _np ("no prefetch") suffix prevent a possible prefetch operation from being inserted by the compiler". Does it mean that the compiler may mess up my code by reordering instructions? Should I always use the "_np" version? I tried both functions and the resulting machine code is the same. Any hints?

Comment: x86 [prefetch instructions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PREFETCHh.html) are hints only; they don't change the memory ordering semantics.  They can affect performance, though.

Comment: Ah, good! I didn't figured out that we must take the expression "prefetch operation" in its literal meaning (but I'd have written "PREFETCH instruction" instead). I suggest to promote your comment in an official answer.

Comment: I don't develop for Windows, so I'll leave it for someone else who knows anything about those Windows functions and their MSVC implementation to write an answer that says something useful and interesting about them.